# Why is Alpha Pig's symbol a triangle?

Tags: character, super-why

In *Super Why!*, the super readers each have their own symbol. Super Why has a book, which fits with his power to read. Princess Presto has a star, which fits with her wand. Red has a spiral, which fits with her skating. And the dog has a dog bone.

Why does Alpha Pig have a triangle?

Bonus points if it's related to the triangle-obsessed pig on Peg + Cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just a triangle, it's a pyramid.  Alpha Pig is a builder.  Ancient Egyptians were builders.  They built the Pyramids of Giza (among others).

Comment: I'll buy that for a dollar.